Simple Simulink modell of a diesel engine, controlled system. System does not want achieve setpoint?
I am trying to create a simple modell of a diesel engine for my boat. I want to see if there is optimization room for the propeller if I switch to a DC engine.
This is what I've gotten so far
The overall system, with setpoint going into the script
This is the inner script
the script then puts out power and gets divided by rad/s to get the Torque. The torque gets a load from the propeller in the water, then the inertia and integration makes it rpm again or rad/s.
This is the engine performance sheet
Any help is appreciated!
/Simon
I can not get it to go to the set point. I think that the issue is that once the torque and load are equal the output is zero and the system stops. But I want it to keep going, up to 3600 rpm.

Well it seems that you have no controller here.
Besides, your Matlab function gives you the maximum amount of power the engine can output at a given speed, so it should receive the actual speed as input.
Here's what I would do :

Note 1: I set aside some trivial conversions here, but do not forget them.
Note 2: I would suggest you use a non-constant load. A quadratic one, crossing the 53N.m value at 20kW would be better: your propeller won't rotate backwards at the beginning of the simulation. Besides, that would be a more realistic load.
